# Executing code examples from the Leptonica image processing library

Tags: c, linker, compilation

I am trying to compile then execute the Leptonica example program `colorquant_reg.c`

**Facts:**

- **OS:** Ubuntu
- **Location:** `leptonlib-1.67/src/colorquant_reg.c`

  (I moved it to `src` since I didn't now how to tell the compiler that the missing `allheaders.h` library file is located in `/src` and not in the original location of `colorquant_reg.c` of `leptonlib-1.67/prog`)
- **What I tried:** `gcc -I. colorquant_reg -o out`
- **Expected result:** An executable I could use to color quantize a `.tif` file of mine.
- **Error:**

  ```
  /temp/cckdQZcM.o: In function main':
  colorquant_reg.c:(.text+0x37: undefined reference to regTestSetup
  colorquant_reg.c:(.text+0xa5: undefined reference to regTestCleanup
  /tmp/cckdQZcM.o: In function TestImage'
  colorquant_reg.c:(.text+0xe0: undefined reference to pixRead
  ```
- **Question 1:** How do I go about and compile this program?
- **Question 2:** Is the undefined reference popping up because of me missing to include something further?

cheers

Comment: Those are link errors - you need to either link the right library to get these missing functions or perhaps compile some additional files which are part of the package that you are playing with

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I've done:

- Download http://www.leptonica.com/source/leptonlib-1.67.tar.gz
- Extract it to `/home/misha/src`
- `./configure; make`
- copy `prog/colorquant_reg.c` to `/home/misha/Desktop/stackoverflow`
- optionally, edit `/home/misha/Desktop/stackoverflow/colorquant_reg.c` to your liking -- it's not part of the library anymore.  So I guess this is where you can add your new headers, etc.

Then, from `/home/misha/Desktop/stackoverflow`, I can compile the file using this command:

```
export LIBLEPT=/home/misha/src/leptonlib-1.67/
gcc colorquant_reg.c -I$LIBLEPT/src -L$LIBLEPT/src/.libs -llept -o colorquant_reg.out
```

The first line is just for convenience -- we can now use `$LIBLEPT` to refer to the long pathname.  The second line is what does the compilation:

- `-I` tells the compiler where to look for the include files
- `-L` tells the compiler where to look for the library files (for the linker)
- `-llept` tells the linker to link with leptonica (it will look for `liblept.so`
- `-o` specifies the output file, which now lives in `~/Desktop/stackoverflow/colorquant_reg.out`

Comment: Can you tell where does `-llept` option come from? I have build leptonica in windows using cygwin though it was build successfully, Programs weren't compiled until using `-llept`. I have no idea how it worked. Please can you tell me how it worked?